# MySQL: Add partition to existing table(with data)?

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 1 million records. As my query will maily based on one column(32 constants). I am trying to add 32 partitions  use type list.

My application can't stop, there will be insert some record in the meanwhile? Can I add partition to the table? Does it impace my application. Such as lock some rows duirng the partition.

I search the internet, but didn't find too much material abou the story of Add partition to existing table?

THank you.

Comment: When you run the partitionioning the table gets a write lock, so no record will be inserted but the application may have some delays or errors, you should find a time range to do this when the application have low activity

Comment: Thank you Nico.  Where did you get the information, could you share the link?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-limitations.html , quote "Table locks.  The process executing a partitioning operation on a table takes a write lock on the table..."

Answer (score 5):

A common way to do a table migration such as this without any impact to the application is to follow these steps:

1. Create a duplicated table that contains the revisions you require (in your case the partition)
2. Setup a trigger on the original table to insert into the duplicated table (this will act as a form of replication for a short period of time)
3. Start a migration from the original table to the new table, at a rate that will not hinder your application (say 1000 rows at a time)
4. When the migration completes, you'll have your tables in perfect sync, this is the time for you to modify your application to start reading and writing using the new table.
5. Once you're happy that your app is functional using the new table, drop the old table.
6. Migration complete, have a beer.